# Mostrar titulo del modal recorriendo foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy intentando de recorrer un foreach que tengo separado por categorias done muestro breves descripciones de cada categoria dentro. El titulo siempre me pone el mismo titulo y no consigo recorrerlo correctamente os dejo el codigo para que le eches un vistazo en que ver me esta fallando que seran varias cosas seguro.

```
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($categoria as $listado1)
        <div class="col xl4 m4 s12">
            <div class="card deep-purple lighten-2 z-depth-3">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal4"><img class="activator" src="http://backend.imaginarqultural.es:81/storage/{{ $listado1->url }}" alt="{{ $listado1->name }}"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-lighten-4">{{ $listado1->titulo }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
         <!-- Modal Structure -->
        @foreach($categoria as $listado1)
        <div id="modal4" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content grey lighten-4">
                <h4>{{ $listado1->titulo }}</h4>
                @foreach($portfolio as $listado2)
                    @if($listado2->category_id == $listado1->id)
                <p>{{ $listado2->actividad }}, {{ $listado2->lugar }}<p>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer grey lighten-4">
                <a href="#!" class="deep-purple lighten-3 modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-purple btn-flat yellow-text text-accent-1">Aceptar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás poniendo los modals y el enlace para abrirlos dentro de un foreach (dos en realidad, pero para el caso es el mismo), entonces todo tus modals van a tener el mismo id

```
@foreach($categoria as $listado1)
    <div id="modal4" class="modal">
    ...
```

lo que no está permitido en html https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id.
Y también todos los enlaces apuntan también al mismo modal

```
@foreach($categoria as $listado1)
    ...
    <a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal4">
```

Una forma de evitarlo puede ser agregando el valor de `$loop->iteration` (La iteración actual del bucle https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) a la id de cada modal, para que sea única, y por supuesto, tendrás que hacerlo también en el href del enlace para abrir cada modal. Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($categoria as $listado1)
        <a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal4{{ $loop->iteration }}">{{ $listado1->titulo }}</a>
    @endforeach

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    @foreach($categoria as $listado1)
    <div id="modal4{{ $loop->iteration }}" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>{{ $listado1->titulo }}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

quité las etiquetas que no son relevantes para que se note mejor cual es el punto de lo que estoy diciendo. En tu código solo deberías agregar `{{ $loop->iteration }}` al `id` de los modals y al `href` de los enlaces.

Como nota, no son necesarios 2 foreach, puedes poner tambien el modal en el foreach que ya tienes:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($categoria as $listado1)
        <a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal4{{ $loop->iteration }}">{{ $listado1->titulo }}</a>

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div id="modal4{{ $loop->iteration }}" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>{{ $listado1->titulo }}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```